# Python error: list indices must be integers, not unicode

Tags: python, file-io, tkinter

there is my problem:
i'm trying to get all numbers from a Tkinter's text widget(get's the text from a file) this way:

```
text = self.text_field.get(1.0, 'end')    
s = re.findall("\d+", text)
```

***s*** returns something like this:

```
[u'0', u'15', u'320', u'235', u'1', u'1', u'150', u'50', u'2', u'2', u'20']
```

than i try to add tags to the text widget:

```
for i in s: self.text_field.tag_add('%s', '5.0', '6.0') %s[i]
```

and it gives an error:

```
list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

thanx for helping me :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python when you do

```
for x in L:
    ...
```

inside the body loop `x` is already the list element, not the index.

In your case the correction needed is simply to use `% i` instead of `% s[i]`.

If in other cases you need both the list element and the index number the common Python idiom is:

```
for index, element in enumerate(L):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The message says it all. When fetching i-th element of a list you cannot use a unicode value (nor a string one) you need to provide an i which is an integer.

One thing which is not clear. If you already assign each element of the `s` list to variable called `i`, then why do you so the lookup in the list again (`s[i]`)? I would try with:

```
for i in s: 
      self.text_field.tag_add('%s', '5.0', '6.0') % i
```